# How to escape single quote in value for sfdx force:data:record:update

Tags: salesforcedx

I am updating a sObject with this sfdx data command

```
sfdx force:data:record:update -u adminUser@mysandbox -s Consignment_Contract__c -i a2N0P000001yhXYXYXY -v "Reason__c='Customer\'s Bank declined'" --json
```

and no matter what variation of the quotes in key/value pair I try I get the following error

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "name": "SfError",
    "message": "Malformed key=value pair for value: Bank",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "context": "Update",
    "stack": "SfError: Malformed key=value pair for value: Bank
        at Function.wrap (path\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfError.js:61:25)
        at Update.catch (path\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:283:38)
        at async Update._run (path\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:106:13)
        at async Config.runCommand (path\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\config\\config.js:272:25)
        at async run (path\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\main.js:76:5)\nCaused by: Malformed key=value pair for value: Bank
        at path\\@salesforce\\plugin-data\\lib\\dataCommand.js:155:23
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Update.transformKeyValueSequence (path\\@salesforce\\plugin-data\\lib\\dataCommand.js:151:23)
        at Update.stringToDictionary (path\\@salesforce\\plugin-data\\lib\\dataCommand.js:121:21)
        at Update.run (path\\@salesforce\\plugin-data\\lib\\commands\\force\\data\\record\\update.js:24:39)
        at Update._run (path\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:102:51)
        at async Config.runCommand (path\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\config\\config.js:272:25)
        at async run (path\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\main.js:76:5)",
    "warnings": [],
    "commandName": "Update"
}
```

Other variations in the payload I have tried

"Reason__c='Customer's Bank declined'"

'Reason__c="Customer's Bank declined"'

'Reason__c="Customer\'s Bank declined"'

"Reason__c='Customer\'s Bank declined'"

Use java Encoding 
(https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

"Reason__c='Customer\u2019s Bank declined'"

throws this error

"name": "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST"

Remove the single quote

"Reason__c='Customers Bank declined'"

throws this error

"name": "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST"

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts need escape characters, too, and they happen to use... you guessed it, backslash (`\`). The following should work:

```
sfdx force:data:record:update -u adminUser@mysandbox -s Consignment_Contract__c \ 
 -v "Reason__c='Customer\\'s Bank declined'" -i a2N0P000001yhXYXYXY --json
```

*(Note, the `\` at the end of the first line allows copy-paste if you want to try it, but I'd recommend manually typing this in as you would with your example).*

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. That does not work. Seems like bug, because Customer\\'s ends up being Customers. So seems like sfdx force:update library gulps the single quote.